# slideshow and overflow

Tags: css

I can't make a div with an overflow to work properly..

the table inside the div with overflow has the same width as the div?!

http://jsfiddle.net/bRbyr/

```
div.slideshow_inner {
    margin:12px 20px 0px 15px;
    width:340px;
    height:440px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:blue;
}

#slideshow_film > tbody > tr > td {
    width:340px;
    background:red;
}

<div class="slideshow_inner">
    <table id="slideshow_film">
        <tr>
            <td>PIC 1</td>
            <td>PIC 2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: the div has the same with as each td, but all td's together has the same width..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- Set `width: 200%` (`number of pictures * 100`) on `#slideshow_film` if you know the number of pictures beforehand:
  http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/bRbyr/3/
- Or, you can stop using a `table` and use `div`s with `display:  inline-block` and then `white-space: nowrap` on the parent:
  http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/bRbyr/4/